# Javascript and Python integration in backend

Tags: python, node.js, web, backend, transpiler

The project I'm working on is like an online compiler, but the problem is the backend receives an intermediate representation of code (a graph), which has to be converted into python code and then run.
The backend will be using NodeJS. I was wondering what the best way is to do this.

1. Convert graph to code in JS, then run the python code.
2. Pass the graph to a python program, which converts it and executes accordingly.

At end the results will be sent to frontend through NodeJS.

Comment: I can't imagine an objective reason why one method would be better than the other. It just depends on which language you find it easier to write the conversion code in.

Comment: @Barmar By efficiency?

Comment: You can't determine which one is more efficient unless you implement both and compare. There's nothing inherent in the two languages that would make one obviously more efficient than the other.